# create a structured table

Tags: awk

I have a file which is as follows

```
Tran No       Date        Vchr No                Debit                         Credit

1239       05/06/2015   115                     750.00                       .00
instal     A Roy                        Sr/Ag/Pol No : 33333
being the exp towards tour
neft ac no 00088888

1295       10/06/2015    123                    400.00                        .00
instal    P Paul                        Sr/Ag/Pol No :54322
being the mobile bill payment
neft zc no 00222222
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
1239       05/06/2015     115                      750.00                       .00            A Roy        33333      being the exp towards tour
1295       10/06/2015      123                      400.00                      .00            P Paul       54322      Being the mobile payment
```

Can I achieve the result using `awk`?

Comment: Thank you,it was indeed helpful. Is python of any help in manipulating such text files?

Answer (score 1):

According to introdused sample date much easy do the task with `sed`

```
sed -n '/^12[0-9][0-9]/{N;N;s^\n\|\s*Sr/Ag/Pol\s*No\s*:\s*\|\s\s\+^\t^gp;}' file
```

or, if you like, with `awk`:

```
awk '/^12/,/:/{sub("\\s*Sr/Ag/Pol No :\\s*","\t"); NF=NF; printf $0" "}/being/' OFS='\t' file
```